# Regex expression for odd # of a's and odd # of b's

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex in the language {a,b} that accepts all string with an odd number of a's and an odd number of b's.

Here is my latest and closest try:

```
(((aa+bb)*(ab+ba))*+((ab+ba)(aa+bb)*)*)
```

The grader says that it failed on "", which I assume means it accepts lambda but I do not see how. This does not mean that this is the only thing wrong.

Help please!

Comment: What is language {a,b}?

Comment: Why would it not accept the empty string? Everything in your regex is optional.

Comment: @melpomene, the problem is that it shouldn't match the empty string ;)

Comment: @trincot "*it accepts lambda but I do not see how*"

Comment: Yes, that is the question, but still it shouldn't match by the mere definition of the challenge (odd a, odd b)

Comment: This is annoying to think about in terms of regexes. It's much easier to draw a DFA for it.

Comment: The logic would probably be a lot easier if you're allowed to use lookahead, is that permitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt has several issues:

- Indeed "" is matched (and shouldn't): all parts of your regular expression are optional
- `abab`, `abba`, ... etc would be matched as well because `((aa+bb)*(ab+ba))*` could be matching an even number of times.
- The same goes for the second half of the regular expression

Here is one that would do the trick:

```
(aa+bb)*(ab+ba)((aa+bb)*(ab+ba)(aa+bb)*(ab+ba))*(aa+bb)*
```

Here the first `(ab+ba)` part is not optional, so "" would not match.

There are four states to consider:

1. even number of a's, even number of b's (initial state)
2. even number of a's, odd number of b's
3. odd number of a's, even number of b's
4. odd number of a's, odd number of b's (target state)

`(aa+bb)*` is state invariant: the state before the match is the same as the state after the match.

`(ab+ba)` swaps state 1 with state 4 and vice versa (and state 2 with state 3 and vice versa, but we're not interested in that)

`((aa+bb)*(ab+ba)(aa+bb)*(ab+ba))*` is state invariant, but it allows the state to go to any other state and come eventually back to the original, ... in all possible ways. When this pattern is executed, the starting state is 4, and so it also exits at that state.

If we take out all the state invariant parts, only `(ab+ba)` is left over, which transitions the initial state to the target state.

All allowed atomic state changes are covered in this expression.

Comment: Oh ok I see. Thank you so much you are a life saver!

Comment: (aa+bb)*(ab+ba)((aa+bb)*(ab+ba)(aa+bb)*(ab+ba))*(aa+bb)*

This regex will accept 'ab' or 'ba' which violet the rule

Comment: @Ahm3dSaid, which rule does it violate? The rule is that it *"accepts all string with an odd number of a's and an odd number of b's"*.